# Exception ignored in: <function BaseMySQLSocket.__del__ at 0x000002B15E76E5E0>

Tags: python, mysql, exception

I have this strange error in my code, it started to show just like that - no changes in the code.

**The same code is working with no problems when I run it from pythonanywhere account**, so it's something with my machine I guess.
Here's the code:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host='localhost',
  user='root',
  database='testdb'
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")

db_result = mycursor.fetchall()
```

full error:

```
Exception ignored in: <function BaseMySQLSocket.__del__ at 0x000002B15E76E5E0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 149, in 
__del__
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 137, in 
shutdown
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

I've reinstalled python-mysql package, tried to upgrade it - no result.

Comment: Are you closing your connection (`mydb.close()`)?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60862442/sqlalchemy-catching-classes-that-do-not-inherit-from-baseexception-is-not-allo) is similar.

Comment: I do not, I'll add closing connection and let you know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got this error in combination with the [Pillow (PIL)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library: I have not found a solution but I have found that if I do not use `image.show()` then the error does not occur.

Here's my full code to replicate the error:

```
import mysql.connector
import PIL.Image

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="example.com",
    user="root",
    password="password",
    database="example_database")

mycursor = conn.cursor()
mycursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM example_table LIMIT 1")

image = PIL.Image.open("test.jpg")
image.show()

mycursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 149, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Michael\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 137, in shutdown
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

To avoid the error, remove the line `image.show()`.